# What is Causing Such a High Load on CPU (From MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

My site has just recently run into some issues with High CPU usage from MYSQL.  When I check the Parallels Power Panel, it says that this: "**/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/exa.example.com.pid --skip-external-locking**" is using a high % of the CPU and the site becomes real slow.

I have checked every MySQL query on the entire site and there is nothing that should cause a long term problem like this.  When I disable the routing file on the site, the load goes way down (almost 0%).  As soon as it is turned back on, up to 100%.  I came into work today to find that the server was down because of this.

The db has no more than 200,000 total records split up into 10 tables.  I am starting to think that maybe the process(es) aren't finishing (hanging) or something else is wrong.  You can load a page or two before the site comes to a stop.

What kind of ideas should I consider?  I am somewhat of a newbie at configuring php and mysql so I haven't experimented with that too much yet.

UPDATE:

I've added this to the mysql config file:

```
log-slow-queries = log-slow-queries.log

long_query_time = 5

log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Does that look okay?  Of course, once I added that, the site seems to load a little better and the log file hasn't had anything written to it yet...

Comment: When I "Kill" the MySQL process, the server load goes down from 99.95% to 5% - 30% and varies from there.  It eventually creeps up to the 90's again.  The pages have caching so when the pages are loaded, they cache.  If the Process is Killed when a page is loading, the page is cached with a mysql warning.  This is very annoying.  I would love some help :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider enabling and then examining the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html), to help you find problematic queries.

Also you say that you "checked every MySQL query" - how? Did you run `EXPLAIN` plans for all of them? Sometimes queries can behave in ways that you don't expect.

Comment: I tested the queries and added limits and such. I will have to read about using the slow query log.  I will get back to you.  Thanks

Comment: I cannot find the config file for the mysql db.... on the phone with the host company.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What database engine are you using? MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I've found the file finally but I am trying to figure out the command(s) to use.  MyISAM